# How to get the classes task for a JavaExec task in gradle to depend on another task?

Tags: gradle

Is this even possible? I have something like:

```
task taskB(dependsOn: taskA) {
    // Do stuff.
}

task taskA {
    // Do stuff.
}

task runClass(dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.some.package.MainClass'
    classpath = some.classpath
}
```

I want to run `taskB` before `classes` in the JavaExec task. How might I go about this? Changing it to `dependsOn: ['taskB', 'classes']` doesn't appear to help -- it still does `classes` first.

**Edit:**

Adding `classes.dependsOn taskB` seems to have worked. Is this the best way, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gradle, `foo.dependsOn(bar, baz)` is equivalent to `foo.dependsOn(bar); foo.dependsOn(baz)`. It does *not* imply any order between `bar` and `baz`, like it would in Ant (with its *soft dependencies* feature).

Can you shed some light on what `taskB` does, and why you think that it needs to run before `classes`?

EDIT:

Based on your comments below, I'd do something like:

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "build/taskB" // output dir of taskB
processResources.dependsOn(taskB)
```

Of course this can be refined in many ways, but it gets the basics right.

Comment: `taskB` copies some files into the source tree. Actually, I technically need it to run before `processResources`, which actually the task that copies the resource files (which `taskB` copied files into). I'm guessing `classes` depends on `processResources`... but it's probably safer to have `processResources` depend on `taskB`.

Additional context: it's a DropWizard project and the resources has UI files. `taskB` runs grunt to create a distribution of UI files to copy to the resources that DropWizard will eventually use.